# Precision is going down as the testing sample increases why?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, precision-recall

I trained the random forest machine learning model with 100K records (overall 700k records) with 297 features with 100 trees

```
    library(randomForest)
        rf_model <- randomForest(as.factor(train$BILL) ~ .,
        data = train,ntree=100,importance=TRUE,
        nodesize = 1,norm.votes = TRUE,
        do.trace = TRUE, type = "classification")
```

when I tried with 14.5k records of test samples I am getting acceptable below results in precision.

```
(precision <- diag(conf_matrix) / rowSums(conf_matrix))
       0         1         2         3         4 
0.9841226 0.9006085 0.5000000 0.7164179 0.8666667
```

But when I tried with a 100k number of test samples my precision is going down.

```
(precision <- diag(conf_matrix) / rowSums(conf_matrix))
       0         1         2         3         4 
0.9953688 0.7729636 0.2241379 0.4438254 0.5869565 

Can anyone logically explain to me what is going on with my model?
Am I overfitting the data if yes what is the possible solution if not what am I doing wrong?
Am I using too much of test sample?
```

Comment: How did you find any data to train on, given that 100k test samples must exhaust all 100k records that you have?

Comment: I have 700K records with randomly splitting the data into 2 (350k) records. 
in the first split I used 100k for training and from the 2nd split I used 100k for testing

Comment: there are 2 possibilities, without additional info. 

1. Your dataset is largely imbalanced. Random forests are not very good with such datasets. 2. You might want to find the best number of trees by doing a preliminary error stabilization, where you calculate OOB error estimates for a range of `n_trees` and find the best `n_tree` that gives you the least error. 

I highly doubt your model is getting overfit, cos random forest rarely do. Other possibilities that i am not sure of: 1. Try using the rest of the data for training. 2. Cross validation (not necessary but worth a try).

Comment: @entrophy yes my data is largely imbalanced  0 - majority class with (98k)records and rest are the remaining classes. But according to author of the paper http://statistics.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/tech-reports/666.pdf it should handle the imbalance

Comment: Yes, you will probably have to use the techniques in the paper, if imbalanced dataset is the issue. either, 1. incorporate class weights into the Random Forest classifier, or 2. grow each tree on a more balanced dataset. I am not sure if these are already implemented in the R's `randomForest` function.